# How to use ml-gradle to load modules on rest server with 2-way SSL

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, ml-gradle

I am trying to configure ml-gradle to load modules on an environment that is setup with 2-way SSL, but am not finding much documentation on how I should specify my Certificate in the gradle.properties . There are brief instructions at https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Loading-modules-via-SSL for a basic setup but many of the links to examples appear to have changed, and there isnt any info on specifying the client cert.

Thanks,
--Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally there's a PR for an example of this - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/pull/323 . I have to review it and try it out locally, but it hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Now documented with example: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/ssl-2way-project